# JBOSS Security: web.xml vs. jboss-web.xml

Tags: java, security, authentication, jboss, web.xml

What is the relation between `web.xml` and `jboss-web.xml`?  Seems like:

---

- Jboss-web.xml

  - specifies the security domain (*which can be found in login-config.xml*)

---

- web.xml

  - specifies what the security level is

---

I don't understand what happens when jboss-web.xml specifies a weak security domain.  Ie: one that cannot do what web.xml specifies.  What happens then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your general question, web.xml is the standard J2EE configuration file and is server-agnostic and its configurations will work with any J2EE compliant application server.

jboss-web.xml are JBoss specific extensions and abilities that exist only in JBoss (that is, another application server from another vendor may do that function, but it configures it differently). login-config.xml is also jboss specific, which is why you need a vendor specific configuration to tie the war and the login together.

I don't know if it is possible to have a configuration problem other than the JBoss security being too lax, but if there is a serious misconfiguration, I would expect JBoss to throw an error on deployment and fail to deploy the war.

Comment: @Yishai, Thanks for the quick response.  That is very helpful.  I am going to leave the question open for a day or two to see if I get any more specific info.